# What is the proper way to build this code on Windows 10?

Tags: c, linux, windows, makefile, compilation

I need some help with building this C code on Windows 10. Trouble is, the methods I have so far used don't seem to work (MinGW, Visual Studio Developer Tools etc.). 
Unfortunately, I only have a very limited understanding of how makefiles should be handles in operating systems other than Linux. 
Can you please take a look at the files (see the link below) and check whether the code can be compiled using Windows. If so, how can I do that? 
Thank you! 
https://github.com/embeddedartistry/embedded-resources/tree/master/examples/c

Comment: Makefiles are mostly a (painful) thing of the past. You would simply create a project in your favourite IDE, add all files, click "build", done. Learning some make file syntax is a big waste of time in the year 2018.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows 10 btw. Same problem with 7, Vista, XP, ...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for that project says to use [premake](https://github.com/embeddedartistry/embedded-resources#premake5).  You still need a compiler like `MinGW`. Note that `MinGW` has build tools like `make` separately as part of `MSYS`.